# Initialization/storing variabile for many functions

Tags: java

I have sample code. I need to get rid of `arg2` from `f1` and `f2`.

```
public void initialize(int arg1) {
    //arg2 initialization
    int arg2 = 0;
    f1(arg1, arg2);
    f2(arg1, arg2);
}

f1(int arg1,int arg2){
    //do sth
}

f2(int arg1, int arg2){
    //do sth
}
```

I tried to initialize it in each function, but when you have, for example 15 functions and instead of integer you have big HashMap it's too expensive to initialize it every time.

```
public void initialize(int arg1) {
    f1(arg1);
    f2(arg1);
}

f1(int arg1){
    int arg2=0;
    //do sth
}

f2(int arg1){
    int arg2=0;
    //do sth
}
```

I also want to avoid creating variable as static. Have you any ideas of storing that?

Comment: I don't understand why not static, or at least a class variable since it really seems it is.

Comment: Put it as a class member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it as a field?

```
private int arg2 = 0;
public void initialize(int arg1) {
    arg2 = 0;
    f1(arg1);
    f2(arg1);
}

f1(int arg1){
    //do sth
}

f2(int arg1){
    //do sth
}
```

Assuming `f1` doesn't change the value of `arg2`, this would work in exactly the same way.